# Heteroscedasticity test for random effects model in Stata

Tags: stata, random-effects-model, heteroscedasticity

I have a panel data and according to Hausman, I have to use a random effects model. I know that in Stata I can use a modified Wald test, but only with a fixed effects model. I want to know a test for heteroscedasticity with a random effects model.

Comment: Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCzDLRyaVqg) for checking heteroscedasticity in the random effect model.